# Get selected text in webview to highlight it in java

Tags: java, android

I'd like to allow users to highlight in yellow text in my webview.
So I wanna use some javascript to allow my app to get the selected text:

```
mWebview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
new ValueCallback<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Webview selected text: " + value);
    }
});
```

Ok, this will get the selected text in the webview. Now I need to save this texts in sharedpreferences to remember it next time user open the app, then find all the texts saved to highlight. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I really don't know why you just don't do what you are saying?!

Comment: @DrTJ because it is not as simple as it sounds to code.